# How to deploy WSPBuilder developed package on specific Sharepoint site?

Tags: deployment, wspbuilder

I am developing the wsp package, which includes 2 list definitions,a webpart, and a picture library definition in WSPBuilder. I tried with sample webpart. I wondered, there is option given in solution explorer -> right click on Project Name -> sub Menu -> deploy. when i get clicked it, it deployed perfectly. but where ? it did not asked any url. neither at start time nor while deploying.

So what i have to conclude?
Where it should it deployed?
I checked almost all web applications on my server. I could not find the webpart in webpart gallery in each web application.

I am using WSPBuilder 1.4 , Visual studio 2010, Sharepoint foundation 2010.
If i am using wrong configuration please put me in right directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using SP2010, and VS2010 - you might want to think about using the in built SharePoint tooling rather than WSPBuilder.

Secondly, before you will see the webpart you need to enable the feature containing it at the Web or Site level as it has been scoped. Go to Site features within /_layouts/settings.aspx and ensure that the feature containing the WebPart is enabled.

However, as mentioned, I would highly recommend using the SharePoint 2010 tooling in built rather than WSPBuilder for packaging and deployment.

Comment: +1 for not using WSP Builder with the 2010 wave

Comment: Thanks buddy, I am definitely using the sharepoint 2010 tooling for my other projects. I have bit hands on on sharepoint 2010 tooling itself. but this is our a year old project ,where earlier developer used wspbuilder for the same. So I need to get hands on, on wspbuilder to achieve requirements. thats why i am using WSPBuilder. other wise +1 for your recommendation from me too....

Comment: Yes any updates here ? how can i deploy WSPBuilder application in sharepoint 2010 ?

Comment: Yes, i got it, if you right click the project in solution explorere you will get the option for package/deploy. read instructions carefully and add url right there....and say deploy ...it will deploy on specified url...

Comment: Can you put a capture the option where insert the url, i can´t see the right place.
Thanks